# Позиционирование на сайте

Tags: html, css

У меня есть header(шапка) с display:flex,в котором находится много дивов. Я не могу разместить поисковик и картинки(они закомментированы в коде) так, чтобы они заполняли свободное пространство в середине и внизу шапки. Все сдвигается, если их там разместить.

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body,
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    p {
      margin: 0;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 100%;
    }
    body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    a:hover{
      color: #FFFF00;
    }
    a{
       text-decoration: none;
    }
    .header {
      display: flex;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: rgb(95 13 238 / 0.5);
      text-align: center;
    }
    .overlay {
      display: flex;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: rgb(95 13 238 / 0.5);
    }
    .overlay h1 {
      color: white;
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 26px;
    }
    .title-icons{
       margin: 2% 0 0 5%;
       width: 20%;
       height:50%;
    }
    .title-icons img {
       width: 15%;
    }
    .title-icons p{
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 40% 0 0
    }
    .site-info{
       margin: 3% 0 0 0%;
       width: 20%;
       height: 30%;
    }
    .site-info img{
      width: 10%;
    }
    .phone {
        color: white;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 900;
    }
    .phone:hover{
      color: #FFFF00;
    }
    .contact-info{
      width: 35%;
      height: 50px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
     
    .contact-info img{
      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      top: 95%;
      right: 50%;
    }
    .word {
      margin: 0 5px;
      color: white; /* Цвет текста */
    }
    .separator {
      width: 2px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 0 5px;
    }
    .search{
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       width: 80%;
       height: 100%;
    }
    .search input{
      margin: 5% 0;
      width: 320px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .search button{
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-image: url(https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3936/3936453.png);
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .shop-menu{
       width: 20%;
       height: 100%;
       display: inline-flex;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .shop-menu img{
      width: 35%;
      margin: 5% auto;
    }
    .button1{
      width: 80px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: rgb(95 13 238 / 0);
      border: 2px solid rgb(95 13 238 / 0);
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center; /* Выравнивание текста по центру */
      display: flex; /* Используем flex для центрирования текста и изображения */
      justify-content: center; /* Центрирование по горизонтали */
      align-items: center; /* Центрирование по вертикали */
      margin: 50% 1% 0 0;
    }
    .button2{
      width: 80px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: rgb(95 13 238 / 0);
      border: 2px solid rgb(95 13 238 / 0);
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center; /* Выравнивание текста по центру */
      display: flex; /* Используем flex для центрирования текста и изображения */
      justify-content: center; /* Центрирование по горизонтали */
      align-items: center; /* Центрирование по вертикали */
      margin: 50% 5% 0 0;
    }
    .button3 {
      width: 100px;
      height: 30px;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FFD700, #FFFF00);
      border: 2px solid #FFD700;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      transition: background 0.3s ease;
      text-align: center; /* Выравнивание текста по центру */
      display: flex; /* Используем flex для центрирования текста и изображения */
      justify-content: center; /* Центрирование по горизонтали */
      align-items: center; /* Центрирование по вертикали */
      margin: 50% 5% 0 0;
    }
    .button1:hover {
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FFFF00, #FFD700);
    }
    .button2:hover {
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FFFF00, #FFD700);
    }
    .button3:hover {
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FFFF00, #FFD700);
    }
    .container {
      display: flex; /* Установите контейнеру flex-контейнером */
      background-color: #f0fbfe;
    }
    .menu {
      width: 30%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 3% 5% 0 1%;
      background: linear-gradient(135deg, #3399FF, #9933CC);
      text-align: center;
      color: white; /* Цвет текста в меню */
    }
    .catalog-header{
      margin: 5% 0 0 0;
    }
     
    .content {
      width: 770px;
      margin: 5% 0 0 0 ;
      font-size: 0;
      flex:1;
    }
    .card {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 250px;
      height: 450px;
      margin-right: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 25px 25px 30px;
      box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 black;
      position:relative;
    }
    .card button{
      width: 80px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #ff3f46;
      border: #ff3f46;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5%;
      right: 5%;
    }
    .card button:hover {
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0102, #ff0102);
    }
    .no-right-margin {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    .card-price {
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 25px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 4.5%;
      left:5%;
    }
    .card-text {
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .card-image {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .card-width{
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 300;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10%;
      left: 5%;
    }
    .card-art{
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 300;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 17%;
      left: 5%;
    }
    .footer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center; /* Центрировать содержимое по горизонтали */
      align-items: center; /* Центрировать содержимое по вертикали */
      height: 200px;
      background-color: #5f0dee;
    }
    .footer-content {
      text-align: center; /* Центрировать текст по центру */
      color: white;
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    .email {
      margin-top: 10px; /* Добавить отступ между названием и почтой */
      display: block; /* Перенести почту на следующую строку */
       color: white;
      font-size: 18px; /* Уменьшить размер шрифта для почты (по желанию) */
    }
    .footer-author {
      margin: auto;
      color: white;
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    .catalog-link {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #333;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }
    .catalog-link img{
      width: 10%;
      margin: 0 5% 0 0;
    }
    .catalog-subcatalog {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: left;
      margin-left: 10%;
    }
    .catalog-subcatalog-link {
      color: white;
    }
    .catalog-subcatalog-link:hover {
      color: #FFD700; /* Желтый цвет текста при наведении */
    }
    /* Стили для отображения подменю при наведении */
    .catalog-item:hover .catalog-subcatalog {
      max-height: 200px; /* Высота подменю */
    }
    /* Скрытие чекбоксов */
    .sub-menu-checkbox {
      display: none;
    }
    .catalog-link:hover {
      color: #FFD700; /* Желтый цвет текста при наведении */
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
     
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Мир Обоев</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/fonts/fonts.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
      </head>
     
      <body> 
         <header class="overlay">
     
                 <div class="title-icons">
                      <h1 class="header-title"> Мир Обоев </h1>
                      <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/178197/fabric-material.svg" alt="Обои">
                      <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/17547/paint-roller.svg" alt="Валик">
                      <img src="https://library.kissclipart.com/20180830/zfw/kissclipart-paint-bucket-drawing-easy-clipart-drawing-paint-cl-4ba76cb2a6a5fa60.png" alt="Краска">
                      <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/household-items-2/100/glue-1024.png" alt="Клей">
                      <p class="main-text">Интернет магазин<br>от эконом до премиум</p>
                 </div>
     
                 <div class="site-info" >
                  <a class="phone" href="tel:+79289063707"> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6FV2Mqb/pngtree-phone-icon-png-image-1817554-Photo-Room-png-Photo-Room.png" alt="Обои">+7 (928) 906-37-07</a>
                  <p><img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7Vkf5p/png-transparent-computer-icons-clock-angle-illustrator-time-Photo-Room-png-Photo-Room.png" alt="Обои">ежедневно 9:00 — 19:00</p> 
                 </div>
     
                 <div class="contact-info">
                   <a href="#" class="word">О компании</a>
                   <span class="separator"></span>
                   <a href="#" class="word">Новости</a>
                   <span class="separator"></span>
                   <a href="#" class="word">Услуги</a>
                   <span class="separator"></span>
                   <a href="#" class="word">Интересное</a>
                   <span class="separator"></span>
                   <a href="#" class="word">Контакты</a>
                 </div>
     
                 <div class="shop-menu">    
                    <button class="button1"><img  src="https://i.ibb.co/FDrPTry/Location-Larger.png"  alt="Обои"> Город</button>
                    <button class="button2"><img  src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/digital-symbols/100/ECommerce_Digital_Website_Media_Interface_Online-130-1024.png" alt="Обои"> Вход</button>
                    <button class="button3"><img  src="https://i.ibb.co/D11L2Ss/shopping-cart-computer-icons-white-png-favpng-CUXn-L8s3z-Zy-EZLunnr3-Dd-TEQX-removebg-preview.png" alt="Обои"> Корзина</button>
                 </div>
     
                 <!--
     
                <div class="links">
                   <a href=""><img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/telegram-2019-logo.svg"></a>
                   <a href=""><img src="https://deskmed.ru/wp-content/files/photo-1-1536x1536.png"></a> 
                </div>
     
                 <div class="search">
                   <input type="search" id="site-search" name="q" />
                   <button></button>
                 </div>
                 -->
     
         </header>
     
           <div class="container">
                  <section class="menu">
                          <div class="catalog">
                          <div class="catalog-header"><span>Категории</span></div>
                      <ul class="catalog-list">
                          <li class="catalog-item">
                       <label  class="catalog-link">
                                <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/178197/fabric-material.svg" alt="Обои" >
                        <p class="list">Обои<p>
                             </label>
                       <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                             <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                         <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Россия</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Германия</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Италия</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Нидерланды</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Франция</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Китай</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Англия</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Турция</a></li>
                         </ul>
                             </div>                 
                          </li>
                          <li class="catalog-item">
                         <label  class="catalog-link">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/t2KNtpb/650-6500238-png-file-removebg-preview.png" alt="Фотообои">
                       <p>Фотообои</p>
                             </label>
                       <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                             <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                         <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Пейзажи и природа</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Города и архитектура</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Искусство и абстракция</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Детская комната</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Космос и наука</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Еда и напитки</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Интерьер и дизайн</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Праздники и события</a></li>
                         </ul>
                          </li>         
                          <li class="catalog-item">
                         <label  class="catalog-link">
                            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/24636/parquet.svg" alt="Настенные покрытия" >
                        <p>Настенные покрытия</p>
                             </label>
                       <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                             <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                         <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">3D обои</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Текстурные покрытия</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Обои с объемными узорами</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Спецэффекты на стенах</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Флоуресцентные и светящиеся обои</a></li>
                         </ul>
                          </li>         
                          <li class="catalog-item">
                         <label  class="catalog-link">
                     <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/178197/fabric-material.svg" alt="Жидкие обои">
                   <p>Жидкие обои</p>
                             </label>
                       <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                             <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                         <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Текстурные</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Металлические</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Цветные</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">С эффектом мрамора</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Глянцевые</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Декоративные</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">С эффектом стекла</a></li>
                         </ul>
                          </li>         
                      <li class="catalog-item">
                               <label class="catalog-link">
                                <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/household-items-2/100/glue-1024.png" alt="Клей" >
                         <p>Клей</p>
                             </label>
                       <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                             <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                         <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Универсальный</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Для бумажных обоев</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Для виниловых обоев</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Для текстильных обоев</a></li>
                         </ul>
                      </li>         
                      <li class="catalog-item">
                         <label  class="catalog-link">
                        <img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_551306.png" alt="Ламинат" >
                         <p>Ламинат</p>
                     </label>
                       <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                             <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                         <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Paradise</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Ritter</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Winlerk</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">WesterHof</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Egger Pro</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">GreenWald</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">EuroHome</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">AGT</a></li>
                         </ul>
     
                      </li>     
                <li class="catalog-item">
                         <label  class="catalog-link">
                                <img src="https://library.kissclipart.com/20180830/zfw/kissclipart-paint-bucket-drawing-easy-clipart-drawing-paint-cl-4ba76cb2a6a5fa60.png" alt="Краска" >
                        <p>Краска</p>
                     </label>
                       <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                             <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                         <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Paradise</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Ritter</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Winlerk</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">WesterHof</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Egger Pro</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">GreenWald</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">EuroHome</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">AGT</a></li>
                         </ul>
     
                      </li> 
                      <li class="catalog-item">
                         <label  class="catalog-link">
                                <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/178197/fabric-material.svg" alt="Лепной декор" > 
                        <p>Лепной декор</p>
                             </label>
                       <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                             <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                         <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Перфект</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">EuroWood</a></li>
                         </ul>
     
                          </li>                     
                      </ul>
                  </div>
                  </section>    
     
                 <section class="content">
     
                   <div class="card">
                      <img class="card-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/xhDqN50/1879.png"  />        
                      <p class="card-text">Marburg Empire (Германия)</p>
                      <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 4747</h5>
                      <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                      <h3 class="card-price">1150 Р</h3>
                      <button>Купить</button>
                   </div>
     
                   <div class="card">
                      <img class="card-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/F8VPmFq/1878.png" />        
                      <p class="card-text">Zambaiti Parati Canova (Италия)</p>
                      <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 4772</h5>
                      <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                      <h3 class="card-price">1500 Р</h3>
                      <button>Купить</button>
                   </div>
     
                   <div class="card">
                      <img class="card-image"src="https://i.ibb.co/hKzLVHM/1880.png"/>
                      <p class="card-text">Primo Parati TESORO (Италия)</p>
                      <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 5243</h5>
                      <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                      <h3 class="card-price">1800 Р</h3>
                      <button>Купить</button>
                   </div>
     
                   <div class="card">
                   <img class="card-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/2g4c5rk/1877.png"/>
                      <p class="card-text">Erismann Erismann (Россия)</p>
                      <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 4725</h5>
                      <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                      <h3 class="card-price">2400 Р</h3>
                      <button>Купить</button>
                   </div> 
     
                   <div class="card">
                      <img class="card-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/zNd0mKT/1876.png"/>
                      <p class="card-text">Zambaiti Parati Melodia (Италия)</p>
                      <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 4245</h5>
                      <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                      <h3 class="card-price">999 Р</h3>
                      <button>Купить</button>
                   </div> 
     
                   <div class="card">
                      <img class="card-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/HVpqLbS/1875.png" />         
                      <p class="card-text">Zambaiti Parati Melodia (Италия)</p>
                      <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 4443</h5>
                      <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                      <h3 class="card-price">999 Р</h3>
                      <button>Купить</button>
                   </div>
     
                 </section>
     
           </div>
                <footer class="footer">
                   <div class="footer-content">
                      <h4 class="footer-author">Мир Обоев © 2023. All Rights Reserved</h4>
                      <a class="email" href="mailto:makleo2002@gmail.com">Email: makleo2002@gmail.com</a>
                   </div>
                </footer>
      </body>
    </html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]